# osCommerce - Duplicating payment modules

Tags: oscommerce

I'm wondering on how to duplicate a payment module...bascially what I'm trying to do is to have 3 Cash on Delivery modules but with different names. How can I accomplish that? Haven't had any luck finding any answers so I posted this question here..

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone stumbles upon the same problem this is what I found out that works:

Copy the file from catalog/includes/modules/payment/ named cod.php. Replace every instance of the word 'cod' and 'COD' to anything else like 'cash' / 'CASH' for example.

Then upload the new file called 'cash.php'.

Next thing you have to edit two translates which can be found in catalog/includes/languages/english/modules/payment. Copy the cod.php file and replace the words like before.

Thats it